# Firebase Save Data from Comma Separated Value

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below Json Response from my php

[image]

Currently I have below code to insert data to firebase

```
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
        //JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
        String[] stocks = new String[arr.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){

            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

            mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(context.getResources().getText(R.string.bid_request).toString().trim());

            Map<String, Object> userValues = new HashMap<>();
            DatabaseReference newBid=mDatabase.push();
            userValues.put("uid", obj.getString("user_id"));
            userValues.put("uNme",obj.getString("first_name")+" "+obj.getString("last_name"));
            userValues.put("uMoble", obj.getString("user_mobile"));
            userValues.put("uAvtr",  obj.getString("src"));
            userValues.put("uRat",  obj.getString("user_ratings"));

            userValues.put("pck", obj.getString("pickup_location"));
            userValues.put("drp",obj.getString("drop_location"));
            userValues.put("pLat", obj.getString("pickup_latitude"));
            userValues.put("pLan",  obj.getString("pickup_longitude"));
            userValues.put("dLat", obj.getString("drop_latitude"));
            userValues.put("dLan",  obj.getString("drop_longitude"));
            userValues.put("did",obj.getString("driver_id"));
            userValues.put("dMoble", obj.getString("driver_mobile"));        

            newBid.setValue(userValues, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            });
```

it is saving data as below firebase structure

[image]

what I want to do is each comma separated mobile no from json response will be saved as below firebase structure. How can I achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple keys with same name in Json object, one thing you can do is store it as arraylist of String, while adding the data to realtime database, split it with **,** as follows

```
userValues.put("dMoble", obj.getString("driver_mobile").split(","));
```

if  you want to want key a ed:- **mobilenum** with each mobile number try the following solution

```
            List<HashMap<String ,String>> dMobiles  = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String mobilenum:jsonObject.getString("driver_mobile").split(",")){
                HashMap<String,String> mobileMap = new HashMap<>();
                mobileMap.put("mobilenum",mobilenum);
                dMobiles.add(mobileMap);
            }
            userValues.put("dMoble",dMobiles);
```

Comment: it is giving error "Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead" another point if i save in this way then how can i snapshot the value based on mobile no like where mobileno=mobileno

Comment: i have updated the answer, check if this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Here you are taking the entire `,` separated phone numbers as a single string. so the Firebase assumes that to be a single string. To add the phone numbers separately you need to divide the mobile numbers string and store it in an array. With a `foreach` loop to that array, you can add individual numbers with an index.

By the way Firebase will overwrite the value, if same key is used in a single node, so to add each mobile number separately you need to different key value for each mobile number.

Comment: use `String[]  MobileNumbers = obj.getString("driver_mobile").split(",");` and use 

`for (string mobile : MobileNumbers) 
{
    //Access your Individual Mobile Number as strings here.
    //Add each number individually with a different index
    //Goto the **dmobil** node and add the numbers 
}`

Kindly Upvote if that helps! Thank You